# Can I use a chest freezer in an unconditioned garage which often gets very hot and humid?

Tags: appliances, humidity, heat

Do I have to do anything special to use a chest freezer in a garage in Florida which often gets very hot and humid?

Comment: The instruction manual should list the maximum ambient temperature it is rated to work at, [this one](http://products.geappliances.com/ApplProducts/Dispatcher?REQUEST=SpecPage&Sku=FCM7SUWW) says it's rated up to 110 degrees.  If your garage is not air conditioned and exceeds that temperature , then the freezer may not be able to maintain the proper temperature.

Comment: @Johnny That sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to do anything special. People have freezers in houses that are not air conditioned after all.

Obviously keeping it powered and the door closed as much as possible will help keep a stable temperature.

Comment: And, obviously, the hotter the surroundings,  the harder the machine has to work and the more you'll spend on electricity.